# Find the value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n-1)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I will show two solutions of this problem.

First solution :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\int_0^1 (2x^{2n-2}-x^{n-1})dx\right)$$
$$=\int_0^1 \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty(2x^{2n-2}-x^{n-1})\right)dx$$
$$=\int_0^1 \left( \frac{2}{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{1-x} \right) dx $$
$$=\int_0^1  \frac{1}{1+x}dx $$
$$=\ln 2$$

Second solution :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\int_0^1 (2x^{2n-2}-2x^{2n-1})dx\right)$$
$$=\int_0^1 \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty(2x^{2n-2}-2x^{2n-1})\right)dx$$
$$=\int_0^1 \left( \frac{2}{1-x^2}-\frac{2x}{1-x^2} \right) dx $$
$$=\int_0^1  \frac{2}{1+x}dx $$
$$=2\ln 2$$

In fact, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n-1)}=2\ln 2$.

Why the first solution is false but the second is true ?

I have known that uniformly convergent series can be integrated term by term.

Is this mean that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2x^{2n-2}-2x^{2n-1})$ ; second solution,  is  uniformly convergent but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2x^{2n-2}-x^{n-1})$ ; first solution,  is not ?

Comment: You messed up at one of the steps, so I reccomend comparing them

Comment: @AaronThompson What do you mean?

Comment: @AaronThompson $\int_0^1x^{n-1}=\int_0^12x^{2n-1}=\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: I am saying he made a mistake in one of the calculations and was doing it right in the other calculations. It's not like he's doing it two different ways

Comment: @AaronThompson (S)he is doing it in multiple ways

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an even more baffling calculation:

\begin{align*}
0 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{2n} - \frac{1}{n} \right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} (2 x^{2n-1} - x^{n-1}) \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2 x^{2n-1} - x^{n-1}) \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{2x}{1-x^2} - \frac{1}{1-x} \right) \, dx \\
&= - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x+1} \\
&= -\log 2.
\end{align*}

So where did we mess up? It is the third step, where we interchanged the order of integration and summation. In this step, we are actually dealing with $\infty - \infty$ type indeterminate, which are cleverly hidden, and we failed to manage it properly. This is more evident if we plot the graph of the partial sum

$$y = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (2x^{2k-1} - x^{k-1})$$

for $n = 1, \cdots, 20$ as follows. (Color changes from red to green to blue as $n$ increases.)

[image]

The mass of $\log 2$ is concentrated around the high spike at $x = 1$, which vanishes as $n \to \infty$. This is why in both calculation we end up losing $\log 2$.

---

Speaking differently, the common mistake we have done is essentially the same as in the following bogus argument:

\begin{align*}
0
&= \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots \right) - \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots \right) \\
&= \left( \frac{2}{2} + \frac{2}{4} + \frac{2}{6} + \cdots \right) - \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots \right) \\
&= -1 + \left(\frac{2}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{3} + \left( \frac{2}{4} - \frac{1}{4}\right) - \cdots \\
&= -1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} - \cdots \\
&= -\log 2.
\end{align*}

In our calculation, shifting the order of the summand is achieved by doubling the exponent; that is, by changing $\int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} \,dx$ by $\int_{0}^{1} 2x^{2n-1} \,dx$.

Comment: Thank you. But why the second solution is true?

Comment: I have known that uniformly convergent series can be interchanged the order of integration and summation.

Is this mean that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2x^{2n-2}-2x^{2n-1})$ ; second solution,  is  uniformly convergent but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2x^{2n-2}-x^{n-1})$ ; first solution,  is not ?

Comment: @Bless, That's right. We have $$ \left| \frac{1}{1+x} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} (2x^{2k-2} - x^{k-1}) \right| = \frac{x^n (1+x-2x^n)}{1-x^2}, $$ and as $x \to 1$ the right hand side converges to $n-\frac{1}{2}$. So the first one does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Of course, failure of uniform convergence does not necessarily prevent us from interchanging the order, but in our case this certainly does.

Comment: Thank you. Can you show that the second one converge uniformly?

Comment: @Bless, the second one does not converge uniformly, neither. An easy way to see is that, while the partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (2x^{2k-2} - 2x^{2k-1})$ is zero at $x = 1$ the limiting function $1/(x+1)$ is not zero at $x = 1$. But in this case we have at least two different lifesavers: [*Abel's theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) and [*dominated convergence theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). Either way can be used to justify your second argument.